# How can I extract multiple columns based on multiple column-prefix strings within a data frame's colnames?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am struggling in R to write multiple CSV files based on multiple column name substrings from a single data frame `subtractedcounts` with 196 columns. `dim = [44,196]` First 4 columns and rows look like:

```
      X1_tumor X1_normal X2_tumor X2_normal
gene         5         7        8        11
gene2        7         4        9         4
gene3        6         7        6         7
gene4        9         8        9        87
....
```

`subsamples` is a character vector of the 98 different samples first two shown here:

```
[1] "X1_tumor"  "X1_normal"
```

I would like to extract pairs of counts based on matching text within the colnames of `subtractedcounts` such as the first 2 characters "1_" and write them to individual csv files, yielding 98 csv files with two columns of counts, for example: columns = 1_tumor and 1_normal

I have tried many things, including:

```
for subsamples in subtractedcounts
{{(lapply(subsamples, 
 function(y)substring((subsamples[seq(1,98,1)])1,2), y = n) {
 lapply(subsamples, function(x) write.csv(subtractedcounts[,grepl("n",colnames(subtractedcounts))], paste(x, ".csv", sep = "")))
}}
```

This returns 98 CSV files appropriately named but containing all 196 columns (i.e. the entirety of `subtractedcounts`). I want only the two columns containing the appropriate substring such as "1_" . Ideally this would look like:

```
       X1_tumor X1_normal
 gene         5         7
 gene1        7         4
 gene2        6         7
 gene4        9         8
```

The `subtractedcounts` rownames are currently being returned as the first column of the .csv's, which I would like to keep doing.

Comment: You never said explicitly, but `subtractedcounts` is the dataframe at top? Please take care to explain the question more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following example:

```
df = data.frame(x1_normal = c(7,4,7,8),
                x1_tumor = c(5,7,6,9),
                x15_tumor = c(15,17,16,19),
                x3_tumor = c(35,37,36,39),
                x15_normal = c(17,14,17,18),
                x3_normal = c(37,34,37,38))
row.names(df) = c("gene","gene2","gene3","gene4")

> df
      x1_normal x1_tumor x15_tumor x3_tumor x15_normal x3_normal
gene          7        5        15       35         17        37
gene2         4        7        17       37         14        34
gene3         7        6        16       36         17        37
gene4         8        9        19       39         18        38
```

As you can see the columns are mixed. Also ***let's assume*** that for every `x??_tumor` there is a corresponding `x??_normal`

First sort the column names and then loop through them in pairs:

```
sortedNames = sort(colnames(df))

for(k in seq(1,ncol(df),2)){
    print(df[,c(sortedNames[k],sortedNames[k+1])])
}
```

I used print, but you can replace it by `write.csv` and using a filename obtained by extracting the string before the `_` in `sortedNames[k]`

Result of the loop:

```
      x1_normal x1_tumor
gene          7        5
gene2         4        7
gene3         7        6
gene4         8        9

      x15_normal x15_tumor
gene          17        15
gene2         14        17
gene3         17        16
gene4         18        19

      x3_normal x3_tumor
gene         37       35
gene2        34       37
gene3        37       36
gene4        38       39
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, R. Schifini. I was also able to get it to work using the following:

```
for (col in subsamples[1:98]) {
  lapply(col, function(colname) {
     write.csv(subtractedcounts[,grepl(col,colnames(subtractedcounts))],
       paste(colname, ".csv", sep = ""))
  })
}
```